# К какому woocommerce action прицепить скрипт обновления количества товаров?

Tags: ajax, wordpress, woocommerce, filter, action

У меня в хедере возле значка корзины выводится количество товара в корзине с помощью:

```
<?php echo WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_count(); ?>
```

Когда пользователь находится в корзине и удаляет товар, отображение количества товаров в корзине в хедере, разумеется, не обновляется. Я понимаю, что проблема решается ajax-запросом который будет вызываться в случае обновления корзины. Вопрос, какой хук отвечает за апдейт данных корзины и если такой вообще?

P.S. Я понимаю, что как вариант можно отключить обновление данных в корзине ajax-ом и делать reload всей страницы, но хотелось бы не обрубать ajax обновление данных

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Например, у нас есть такая конструкция для вывода корзины:

```
<div id="cart_counts"><?php echo WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_count(); ?></div>
```

Теперь нам нужно обновить эти данные при AJAX-запросах в Woocommerce:

```
function woocommerce_cart_count_fragments($fragments) {
    $fragments['#cart_counts'] = '<div id="cart_counts">'.WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_count().'</div>'; // Обязательно дублируем селектор, т.к. он полностью заменяется
    return $fragments;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_fragments', 'woocommerce_cart_count_fragments', 10, 1 );
```

Официальная документация: https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/show-cart-contents-total/

PS: Так же прошу заметить, что используемый фильтр woocommerce_add_to_cart_fragments подойдет только для версии Woocommerce 2.3+, а для более ранних версий нужно использовать add_to_cart_fragments